# Call Data in different/many request mapping

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I Have some case..

I Have 2 URL in my web service and i want show banner list from db..

this my code in my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="support",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String support(Model model){

    Banner banner = new Banner();
    List<Banner> listBannerWeb = bannerService.getBannerList(banner); 
    model.addAttribute("listBannerWeb",listBannerWeb);

    return "menu/support";
 }

@RequestMapping(value ="news",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String news(Model model){

    Banner banner = new Banner();
    List<Banner> listBannerWeb = bannerService.getBannerList(banner); 
    model.addAttribute("listBannerWeb",listBannerWeb);

    return "menu/news";
 }
```

the banner show but i don't want repeat this code in my all controller for select banner.

```
    Banner banner = new Banner();
    List<Banner> listBannerWeb = bannerService.getBannerList(banner); 
    model.addAttribute("listBannerWeb",listBannerWeb);
```

i use tiles (template) this my jsp code.

```
<c:forEach var="banner" items="${listBannerWeb}">                   
<div class="banner"><img src="${url_Upload}/${banner.name}" /></div>                
</c:forEach>
```

How to best way or simple way or reference for this problem ? i need help..thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of weird that you have to pass an instance to get your list of banner... What about having this code in a private method and then use that method instead of copying the code. Something like that :

```
@RequestMapping(value ="support",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String support(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("listBannerWeb", getBannerList());

    return "menu/support";
 }

@RequestMapping(value ="news",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String news(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("listBannerWeb", getBannerList());

    return "menu/news";
 }

private List<Banner> getBannerList() {

    Banner banner = new Banner();
    List<Banner> listBannerWeb = bannerService.getBannerList(banner); 
    return listBannerWeb;
}
```